# jQuery add row to table after specific index with multiple tables on the screen

Tags: jquery

I have 2 tables on a page at once. I want to only manipulate the bottom table through jQuery by adding a row below the row that is clicked. I've managed to figure out using `this.rowIndex` to add the extra row based on the `<tr>` tag being clicked. But when 2 tables are in the mix, it gets confusing.

I've tried using jQuery ID selectors based on the table ID's but it either doesn't work or only the top row of the table is clickable. I've tried `#tableID > thead > tr","tr#tableID", "#tableID > tr`, etc. The first one works but only for the top row.

I've dumbed it down to the simplest form I could get it in on my fiddle page. In it's current form here, only the top table works. How do I get it so only the bottom table works and have it also ignore the "header" row being clicked?

[Code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/chewywaffles/8meWj/)

JavaScript:

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    html = "<tr><td>Jquery</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td>";
    $('tr').eq(this.rowIndex).after(html); 
});​
```

HTML:

```
<table  id="detail" border=1>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td width="138px"><h5>Campaign Name</h5></td>
    <td width="5%"><h5>Invites Sent</h5></td>
    <td width="5%"><h5>Invites Opened</h5></td>
    <td><h5>Unique Visits</h5></td>
    <td><h5>Referrals Shared</h5></td>
    <td><h5>Inquiries</h5></td>
    <td><h5>Sales Generated</h5></td>
  </tr>
</thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>        
</table>

<br />

<table  id="detail2" border=1>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td width="138px"><h5>Campaign Name</h5></td>
    <td width="5%"><h5>Invites Sent</h5></td>
    <td width="5%"><h5>Invites Opened</h5></td>
    <td><h5>Unique Visits</h5></td>
    <td><h5>Referrals Shared</h5></td>
    <td><h5>Inquiries</h5></td>
    <td><h5>Sales Generated</h5></td>
  </tr>
</thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Test3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>   
</table>​
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Here is an updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/8meWj/8/):

```js
$('#detail2 > tbody > tr').click(function() {
  html = "<tr><td>Jquery</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td>";
  $(this).after(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="detail" border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td width="138px">
        <h5>Campaign Name</h5>
      </td>
      <td width="5%">
        <h5>Invites Sent</h5>
      </td>
      <td width="5%">
        <h5>Invites Opened</h5>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h5>Unique Visits</h5>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h5>Referrals Shared</h5>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h5>Inquiries</h5>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h5>Sales Generated</h5>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Test1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br />

<table id="detail2" border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td width="138px">
        <h5>Campaign Name</h5>
      </td>
      <td width="5%">
        <h5>Invites Sent</h5>
      </td>
      <td width="5%">
        <h5>Invites Opened</h5>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h5>Unique Visits</h5>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h5>Referrals Shared</h5>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h5>Inquiries</h5>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h5>Sales Generated</h5>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> How do I get it so only the bottom table works

Add ID to the selector you are using to attach click event like this: `#detail2 > tbody > tr`

> and have it also ignore the "header" row being clicked?

Wrap non-header rows with `tbody` tag

Answer (score 0):

Change your click function to this:

```
$('#detail2 tr:not(:first)').click(function(){
    html = "<tr><td>Jquery</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td>";
    $('#detail2 tr').eq(this.rowIndex).after(html);

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I forked your fiddle, try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/hyNdC/1/

In case the forked jsFiddle doesn't work, here is the new script:

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    html = "<tr><td>Jquery</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>5</td>";
    $(this).after(html);
});
```